# Import scss variable into Angular component

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

Let's say I have the following Angular component:

```
// src/app/app.component.html
<stars [customColor]="blue">
```

And I have the following scss variable:

```
// src/_styles.scss
$color: blue;
```

How can I use the `scss` variable instead of duplicating `blue`?

To clarify, I want to access `$color` in `app.component.html` or `app.component.ts`.

Apparently it's possible to [configure Webpack in a React app](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript) but I'm not sure if this is possible in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

In your `app.component.scss` (or `star.component.scss`) file just import your styles:

```
@import './../_style.scss'
```

Then you can use your scss var

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as far as I know, this only gives me access to `$color` in `app.component.scss`. How can I access it in `app.component.html` or `app.component.ts`?

Comment: This is not possible. (And I think there is not need).  Make a smal  my.vars.scss and import it to all your sub-components scss.  There are some hacks to read the color code from an element, but it's not a usually way.

Comment: An other way is to use  css variables (not scss):  See: https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for adding to the discussion! I want to be able to change the color of `stars` without having to modify `stars`. See also [Applying the open-closed principle to UI components](https://learnitmyway.com/open-closed-ui/)